# Why is this small example not working any more when using pgfmathparse?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

The following small example worked until `\pgfmathparse{\myvalue+1}\pgfmathresult` was added instead of just `1`. I am not getting any error message, the compiling process just doesn't end. This is the try to compress my actual document to this small example. In my document I am getting the error

> `Illegal parameter number in definition of
>   \pgfplots@stored@current@data. \end{tikzpicture}`

What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2
    ]
    \newcommand{\myvalue}{1}
    \draw (1,\pgfmathparse{\myvalue+1}\pgfmathresult) -- (0, 0);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `\draw (1,\myvalue+1) -- (0, 0);`?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Because my actual expression is more complicated than just adding 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pgfmathparse` uses tex assignments, it doesn't simply expand to the result so you need to do it in advance, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\myvalue}{1}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2
    ]
    \pgfmathparse{\myvalue+1}
    \draw (1,\pgfmathresult) -- (0, 0);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfmathparse` should be used as near as possible to the usage of `\pgfmathresult`; other computations in between might change the meaning of `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: @egreg yes I had it just before the \draw (and it works there) but seems dangerous to embed things like that. in a real example, with more values you could still do the calculations up front but save the results in specific macros

Comment: @egreg oh you just put it back where I had it to start with:-)

Comment: That's another possibility. But I remember a question where the problem was exactly this and, IIRC, it was in connection with the `axis` environment.

Comment: Thanks so far @DavidCarlisle @egreg ! No, it doesn't work just before `\draw`. It compiles, but `\pgfmathparse{...}` then always gives the same result no matter what the input is. I had to define my own macro by `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{1}` and use this instead of `\pgfmathresult`. Shall I change your answer?

Comment: @Rob feel free to edit to whatever works

Comment: Sorry, it's me again. Unfortunately, the solution with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{...}` only works once. I have to calculate many coordinates for my drawing, so I was hoping to reuse the `\myresult` variable (`\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{something}`, `\draw...`, `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{something else}`,`\draw...` etc). All `\myresult`'s turn out to have the value, which was assigned last. How to circumvent this? I would really like to avoid using a different variable name each time.

Comment: I created a separate question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334524/how-to-calculate-many-coordinates-inside-pgfplots-axis-without-using-separate-re