# How to calculate many coordinates inside pgfplots axis in a clever way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

What I want is

[image: wanted]

which could be drawn by the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=-1, ymax=1]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myresultA}{1}
            \fill (\myresultA,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myresultB}{2}
            \fill (\myresultB,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myresultC}{3}
            \fill (\myresultC,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            % Many more \fill and \draw commands which require unique coordinate calculation here
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to avoid using separate variable names for each pgfmath calculation, since I have A LOT to compute. Unfortunately, the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=-1, ymax=1]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{1}
            \fill (\myresult,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{2}
            \fill (\myresult,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{3}
            \fill (\myresult,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            % Many more \fill and \draw commands which require unique coordinate calculation here
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

just gives me

[image: failed]

How to do a lot of calculation without separate result variables? Even better would be inline calculation without using any result variable? Is there a clever way? Of course this is just a small example of what I really like to draw. So my question is more of conceptional nature.

Comment: With the information you gave so far there are plenty of ways to achieve the desired result. So can you be a bit more specific what you really want to calculate and how it should look like? Maybe by adding a sketch with some annotations on it or then as explaining text.

Comment: use another addplot with only marks and give coordinates

Comment: @StefanPinnow I will draw something manually which I don't know precisely, yet. What is clear is that I need calculations for almost every coordinate. Please view it more like a conceptional question.

Comment: @percusse What do you mean? I would be happy about another answer!

Comment: You may use your formulas (here `1`, `2` and  `3`) directly in your coordinates. Ex: `\fill ({1+1+1},0) circle [radius=5p];`

Comment: @PaulGaborit No, doesn't work like this. It gives an illegal parameter number error when using it with a self defined macro inside. And when using it with just simple calculation like yours, all calculations give the same result of the last calculation, again. I wished it was that simple!

Comment: @Rob Define your macros outside the `axis` environment...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I could do that, but I would have to name say 300 variables. I would like to avoid that... I would prefer an inline solution.

Comment: @Rob Without a real example, we can't give good advices...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I don't really see why the actual values are important. Above is a minimal example. Drawing this by using inline coordinate calculations would be fine. I think I would be able to transfer the solution to my actual drawing.

Comment: `\addplot[only marks,mark options={mark size=5}] coordinates{(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)};`

Comment: @Rob Your example is not minimal. It is simplistic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a pgfplots expert, but it looks like pgfplots delay the `\fill` command. So it first run the three `\pgfmathsetmacro` and then the three `\fill` commands.

To overcome this you can put your computations inside `\pgfextra` like this :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=-1, ymax=1]
            \fill \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{1}}
              (\myresult,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            \fill \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{2}}
              (\myresult,0) circle [radius=5pt];
            \fill \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresult}{3}}
              (\myresult,0) circle [radius=5pt];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! It's not only `\fill`, it's also `\draw` and everything else which requires coordinates. Quote from the manual regarding `\pgfextra`: "Note that this operation should only be used by real experts and should only be used deep inside clever macros, not on normal paths." So I have some concerns about using it. However it works perfectly! Please allow me to wait a little longer for other answers before I accept yours.

Comment: Here, the `let` operator (from `calc` library) may provide the same possibilities...